# Convert Large CSV DTM to tm package DTM

Tags: r, csv, text-mining, tm

I have a large csv file (3.8 Gb) with data in column (term), row (document) format. I would like to convert this to a dtm from the tm package.

I am skipping the `read.csv` step here, but you get the idea.

```
dtm <- structure(list(the = c(2L, 1L), apple = c(0L, 2L), dumb = c(1L, 0L)), .Names = c("the", "apple", "dumb"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

I then don't know how to convert this to a formal tm package dtm:

```
c <- Corpus(DataframeSource(dtm))
```

That's wrong, obviously.

Thanks for any direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it:

```
tmDTM <- tm::as.DocumentTermMatrix(slam::as.simple_triplet_matrix(dtm),
                                   weighting = tm::weightTf)
```

The [quanteda](http://github.com/kbenoit/quanteda) package has some nice implementations to this functionality as well.